# Seleção Elementos

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho seguinte estrutra abaixo de HTML,gostaria de saber, como faço ao clicar no button,consigo pegar valor do elemento da td class="descricao" anteior que dentro do escopo da tr.

```
<tr>
    <td class="descricao">Texto01</td>
    <td class="btn-l"><button type="button">Leitura Confirmada</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="descricao">Texto02</td>
    <td class="btn-l"><button type="button">Leitura Confirmada</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="descricao">Texto02</td>
    <td class="btn-l"><button type="button">Leitura Confirmada</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você vai usar:

- [`jQuery.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) para selecionar o `tr` mais próximo do button na árvore DOM
- [`jQuery.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) para selecionar o `td.descricao`
- [`jQuery.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) para pegar o conteúdo do `td.descricao`

Exemplo:

```js
$('[type=button]').on('click', function() {
    let descricao = $(this).closest('tr').find('.descricao').text();
    console.log(descricao);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="descricao">Texto01</td>
        <td class="btn-l"><button type="button">Leitura Confirmada</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="descricao">Texto02</td>
        <td class="btn-l"><button type="button">Leitura Confirmada</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="descricao">Texto03</td>
        <td class="btn-l"><button type="button">Leitura Confirmada</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Até realizei implementação sugeridas,contudo me torna todos elementos das TR dentro da tag tabela.Não estou executando fução atravé do click.

Código:
 var descricaoDoc = $('[type=button]').closest('tr').find('td.descricao').text();

Comment: Sim, é o esperado mesmo. Você está selecionando todos os botões e buscando todas as descrições. Se você usar no `click` como eu usei, vai pegar apenas a descrição da `tr` do botão clicado. Por isso o `$(this)`, pois se refere ao botão clicado apenas, e não todos os outros.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        el = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.descricao');
        el.css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="descricao">Texto01</td>
        <td class="btn-l"><button type="button">Leitura Confirmada</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="descricao">Texto02</td>
        <td class="btn-l"><button type="button">Leitura Confirmada</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="descricao">Texto03</td>
        <td class="btn-l"><button type="button">Leitura Confirmada</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: O closest não vai funcionar porque `td.descricao` não é _parent_ do `button` em nenhum nível.

Comment: Li errado, agora está concertado.

Comment: Desculpa ser chato, mas `td.descricao` é sibling do parent do button e não do button em si. :|